# Is there a way to remove points from a Mclust classification plot in R?

Tags: r, mclust

I am trying to plot the GMM of my dataset using the Mclust package in R. While the plotting is a success, I do not want points to show in the final plot, just the ellipses. For a reference, here is the plot I have obtained:

[GMM Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOqQa.jpg)

But, I want the resulting plot to have only the ellipses, something like this:

[GMM desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2umCj.jpg)

I have been looking at the Mclust plot page in: https://rdrr.io/cran/mclust/man/plot.Mclust.html and looking at the arguments of the function, I see there is a scope of adding other graphical parameters. Looking at the documentation of the plot function, there is a parameter called type = 'n' which might help to do what I want but when I write it, it produces the following error:

Error in plot.default(data[, 1], data[, 2], type = "n", xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab,  :
formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments

For reference, this is the code I used for the first plot:

```
library(mclust)

Data1_2 <- Mclust(Data, G=15)
summary(Data1_2, parameters = TRUE, classification = TRUE)
plot(Data1_2,  what="classification")
```

The code I tried using for getting the graph below is:

```
Data1_4 <- Mclust(Data, G=8)
summary(Data1_4, parameters = TRUE, classification = TRUE)
plot(Data1_4,  what="classification", type = "n")
```

Any help on this matter will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look under the source code of `plot.Mclust`, it calls `plot.Mclust.classification` which in turn calls `coordProj` for the dot and ellipse plot. Inside this function, the size is controlled by the option `CEX=` and shape `PCH=`.

So for your purpose, do:

```
library(mclust)
clu = Mclust(iris[,1:4], G = 3, what="classification")
plot(clu,what="classification",CEX=0)
```

[image]